# How to prevent SELinux from installing with CentOS 6.5

Tags: selinux, centos6.5

I know I can disable SELinux in CentOS 6.5, but I’d prefer to just not install it at all from the point of the actual, initial installation. But I can’t find anywhere in the CentOS installer to shut it off. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

On some of the Linux **distribution** SELinux is enabled by **default**, which may cause some unwanted issues, if you don’t understand how SELinux works and the fundamental details on how to configure it.

I strongly recommend that you understand *SELinux* and implement it on your environment. But, until you understand the implementation details of *SELinux* you may want to disable it to avoid some unnecessary issues.

To **disable** SELinux you can use any one of the 4 different methods mentioned in this article.
The SELinux will enforce security policies including the mandatory access controls defined by the US Department of Defence using the Linux Security Module (LSM) defined in the Linux Kernel. Every files and process in the system will be tagged with specific labels that will be used by the SELinux. You can use Is -Z and view those labels as shown below:

```
# ls -Z /etc/

-rw-r--r--  root root  system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       a2ps.cfg
-rw-r--r--  root root  system_u:object_r:adjtime_t:s0   adjtime
-rw-r--r--  root root  system_u:object_r:etc_aliases_t:s0 aliases
drwxr-x---  root root  system_u:object_r:auditd_etc_t:s0 audit
drwxr-xr-x  root root  system_u:object_r:etc_runtime_t:s0 blkid
drwxr-xr-x  root root  system_u:object_r:bluetooth_conf_t:s0 bluetooth
drwx------  root root  system_u:object_r:system_cron_spool_t:s0 cron.d
-rw-rw-r--  root disk  system_u:object_r:amanda_dumpdates_t:s0 dumpdates
```

See more suggestions on disabling [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/how-to-disable-selinux-redhat-fedora-debian-unix/#more-518) hope this helps!
Still having problems then I will help but have a look. It comes defult so there's no way of blacking from installing.

Comment: OK. I already know how to disable SELinux; I was hoping to skip the installation altogether, as we won't be using it on this project. Surprisingly, enabling SELinux adds several seconds to boot time, and in our case it is critical to keep boot time as short as possible. Meanwhile, there is little likelihood of unauthorized access, so security isn't a high priority.

Comment: Well. I to have SELinux my boot time is not bad at all my system takes probably around 4 - 6 sec tops on my servers. I been looking online and couldn't find much on how to total wipe the OS clean of SElinux. Now are you a developer? Is that why you need those boot times? You could try upgrading your system hardware